# How to change the GPU used to run a game windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, windows-8-games

I have a Dell 500GB with a 2GB RAM, and NVIDIA GEFORCE 625M

I have a problem forcing my computer to choose the NVIDIA GPU when running games, but it keeps on choosing the Intel graphic card.

I have tried many different solutions i found on the internet:

I updated anything related to graphic cards to the latest version, and change my NVIDIA preferred graphic processor to "High-Performance NVIDIA Processor" after i added the exe file of my game.

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you have the current display driver from both Nvidia and Intel? [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/576560/how-do-i-know-which-of-my-laptop-gpus-are-running-games?rq=1) also [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/601548/how-to-manually-switch-between-two-different-nvidia-gpu-cards-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: @Ramhound can you elaborate, i didn't understand what you meant

Comment: What part of my question isn't clear?

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean by current display driver? and by the way i have tried the solution of the first link and it didn't work